# Problem in validating the add product section

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I wanted to do this validation in add and edit product

I set the [Required] attribute for both item and product but the validation doesn't work and it gives me this error when all fields are empty and when I hit register.

ProductViewModel=>

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد کنید.")]
[StringLength(27, ErrorMessage = "کد پستی باید 10 رقمی باشد.", MinimumLength = 5)]
[DisplayName("نام و نام خانوادگی")]
public string Name { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد کنید.")]
[StringLength(97, ErrorMessage = "کد پستی باید 10 رقمی باشد.", MinimumLength = 10)]
[DisplayName("توضیحات")]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

itemViewModel=>

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد کنید.")]
    [DisplayName("قیمت")]
    public int Price { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد کنید.")]
    [DisplayName("تعداد")]
    public int QuantityInStock { get; set; }
```

Error text:
[image]

Comment: Read [ask], research the error message you get, and don't post pictures of code or errors. Show the code where you validate the input.

Comment: Are you checking `ModelState.IsValid()` before trying to save?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tXRf.png

Comment: Add `jquery.validate.min.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` in view

Comment: It gives the same error as before.

Comment: Make sure jquery validate scripts are loaded in the header before this page renders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an exception caused by the value you store to the database being null.

Add the following code to the Page to make the `Required` attribute take effect:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```